# Using XSLT, remove parent element when child element contains a nil true attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an xml data file. I also have an xslt file that transforms that file.  Here is what I currently have. The original xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="file:///C:/Users/chvl/Desktop/New%20folder%20(2)/UntitledDS.xslt"?>
<L4 type="schema" guid="de2f8f94-8db6-4979-b32f-8db4bfac3f3c" versionNumber="16" DpaLength="4">
<L4 type="group">
    <FirmID type="item">
        <value>872</value>
    </FirmID>
    <FirmName type="item">
        <value>Generic Name Here</value>
    </FirmName>
    <FirmRef type="item">
        <value>LC</value>
    </FirmRef>
    <ReportingEndDate type="item">
        <value>2015-05-31</value>
    </ReportingEndDate>
    <L4 type="group">
        <_x0030_257 type="item">
            <value xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
        </_x0030_257>
        <_x0030_258 type="item">
            <value>1791886</value>
        </_x0030_258>
        <_x0030_725 type="item">
            <value xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
        </_x0030_725>
        <_x0030_726 type="item">
            <value>407897</value>
        </_x0030_726>
    </L4>
</L4>
</L4>
```

And here is the new xml file after going through the xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="file:///C:/Users/chvl/Desktop/New%20folder%20(2)/UntitledDS.xslt"?>
<Root xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="L4" type="schema" guid="de2f8f94-8db6-4979-b32f-8db4bfac3f3c" versionNumber="16" DpaLength="4">
<Main name="L4" type="group">
    <FirmID type="item">
        <value>872</value>
    </FirmID>
    <FirmName type="item">
        <value>Generic Name Here</value>
    </FirmName>
    <FirmRef type="item">
        <value>LC</value>
    </FirmRef>
    <ReportingEndDate type="item">
        <value>2015-05-31</value>
    </ReportingEndDate>
    <Data name="L4" type="group">
        <DataItem dpa="_x0030_257">
            <value></value>
        </DataItem>
        <DataItem dpa="_x0030_258">
            <value>1791886</value>
        </DataItem>
        <DataItem dpa="_x0030_725">
            <value></value>
        </DataItem>
        <DataItem dpa="_x0030_726">
            <value>407897</value>
        </DataItem>
    </Data>
</Main>
</Root>
```

In the original xml, you see the child elements where xsi:nil="true"? Well, when that happens, I need to remove its parent element.  In this example, I would need to remove <_x0030_257 type="item"> and <_x0030_725 type="item"> and all its sub elements.

Now, what I have tried is putting this code at the end of my XSLT.

```
<xsl:template match="/*/*/*/node()[./*/(@xsi:nil = 'true')]|@*">/xsl:template>
```

It works, except it also removes the attributes from my root element and as well as other places. But I need all those attributes. I feel like I'm just one step away from solving this but that step is turning out to be a humongous leap.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the full XSLT with the snippet code to remove the nil parent element (examples above did not run with the snippet to remove the nils).

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>


    <xsl:template match="/*">
    <Root>
       <xsl:attribute name="name"  >
                     <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
       </xsl:attribute>

        <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="/*[type='schema']"> 
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="ignore"/>
             </xsl:when>
             <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
             </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </Root>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*/*[@type='group']">

   <Main>
       <xsl:attribute name="name"  >
                     <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
       </xsl:attribute>

        <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="child::*[type='item']">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="ignore"/>
             </xsl:when>
             <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
             </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </Main>
</xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="/*/*/*[@type='group']">
   <Data>
       <xsl:attribute name="name"  >
                     <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
       </xsl:attribute>     
        <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="child::*[type='item']">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="ignore"/>
             </xsl:when>
             <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
             </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </Data>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*/*/*[@type='list']">
   <Cube>
       <xsl:attribute name="name"  >
                     <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
       </xsl:attribute>     
        <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="child::*[type='item']">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="ignore"/>
             </xsl:when>
             <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
             </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </Cube>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*/*/Filters[@type='group']"/>


    <xsl:template match="/*/*/*/*[@type='group']">
   <xsl:variable name="count">
        <xsl:number/>
   </xsl:variable>   
   <Data grpcnt="{$count}">
       <xsl:attribute name="name"  >
                     <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
       </xsl:attribute>     
        <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="child::*[type='item']">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="ignore"/>
             </xsl:when>
             <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
             </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </Data>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*/*/*/*[@type='item']">
   <DataItem>
        <xsl:attribute name="dpa"  >
                   <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <value><xsl:value-of select="value"/></value>
    </DataItem>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="/*/*/*/node()[./*/(@xsi:nil = 'true')]|@*">

</xsl:template>



</xsl:stylesheet>
```

PS : Keep in mind that the element names change that's why I'm using stars instead of hard coded label names.

Comment: your input XML has multiple roots and prefix xsi is not defined in the xslt

Comment: @wero `xsi:` is related to XSD as does not need to be defined in this case (I haven't looked closely though). The multiple root problem was just a formatting issue, I have fixed it now.

Comment: @MathiasMüller the *input* doc is not well-formed, and the prefix "xsi" needs to be defined since it is used in a xpath location step. Anyway you already have found an answer...

Comment: @wero You are right about the namespace declaration of course, apologies! I realized this now. The input doc also had a formatting problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that just removing `|@*` from the template match of the last template would probably solve the problem:

```
<xsl:template match="/*/*/*/node()[./*/(@xsi:nil = 'true')]">
```

> It works, except it also removes the attributes from my root element and as well as other places.

That's because in your original expression:

```
/*/*/*/node()[./*/(@xsi:nil = 'true')] | @*
```

the `|` or "union" means the following: either everything to the left of `|` or everything to the right of it (given that there is only one such symbol).

Therefore, the expression means: either a node that has a true `nil` attribute **OR** any attribute, anywhere in the document.

Since you mention "humongous" in your question, your expression:

```
/*/*/*/node()[./*/(@xsi:nil = 'true')]
```

is also quite humongous. Only use `/*/*/*/` if the level of nesting is truly important and if you would like to **keep** elements with `nil="true"` in other places.

If the nesting is not important, you will end up with

```
node()[./*/(@xsi:nil = 'true')]
```

Then, `node()` is too general since it is a test for any type of node, not only element nodes. Use `*` instead that refers to elements:

```
*[./*/(@xsi:nil = 'true')]
```

Inside the predicate (`[...]`), there is no need to start with `./` since this context is implicitly assumed anyway:

```
 *[*/(@xsi:nil = 'true')
```

no need for the parentheses:

```
*[*/@xsi:nil = 'true']
```

and if the `xsi:nil` attribute is *only* present when its value is "true", you could even write

```
*[*/@xsi:nil]
```

One last remark regarding this expression: I am guessing you included `|@*` in the expression because you also wanted to exclude all attributes of such elements, right? Don't worry, having

```
<xsl:template match="*[*/@xsi:nil]"/>
```

will not process any attributes or content of those elements.

---

As user wero has pointed out, you also need to declare the XSI namespace in your XSLT stylesheet to make it work:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

More general advice: it seems that you start all templates matches from the document node, making the patterns absolute. That's fine if you are doing this on purpose, but it also restricts the versatility of your XSLT stylesheet.

Comment: That worked great. Thanks for the answer and the detailed explanation.